# Is it possible to check if an input is filled with zeros and act on the result within the trace for a torch model converted to ONNX

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

I want to implement a PyTorch layer to format an input that is optional to a model. The input is a 2D tensor. If it is filled with zeros, the input should be ignored and returns None. If not, the input should be decoded and passed to the next layer.

```
class formatting_layer(nn.Module):
   def forward(self, input):
      no_input_condition = torch.gt(torch.nonzero(input), 0)
      if no_input_condition:
          ***Format the input***
          formatted_input = input
      else:
          formatted_input = None

      return formatted_input
```

When I convert the model to ONNX, I get this tracer warning.

```
Tracer Warning: Converting a tensor to a Python boolean might cause the trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
if no_input_condition:
```

The value of the optional input might change overtime, so the condition can't be treated as a constant. How can I fix this issue without switching to ONNX script mode? Is it possible to get the desired behavior without using control flow? After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76208491/20194718) I thought it would be possible to deal with an optional input set to zero when converting a model to ONNX in tracer mode.

I tried different combinations of torch operations to pass to the conditional operator. I also tried converting the tensor to a Python number but that also generated a tracer warning.
The expected behavior is that the layer returns None if the optional input is filled with zeros and a formatted tensor if it contains other values.
What happens is that the condition always evaluate to the same thing no matter the value of the optional input.

Answer (score 1):

ONNX does not support control flow. If you need to compile a model with control flow, use `torch.jit.script` or `torch.compile`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without control flow?